# github "origin" deletion

Tags: git, github

im trying to delete this "origin" thing so i can actually run the tutorial code from this website

http://www.railstutorial.org/book#sec:github

this is the code im trying to run

`$ git remote add origin git@github.com:delinquentme/first_app.git`

and im getting this returned:

fatal: remote origin already exists

problem is though none of the files are up there!

****UPDATE****

so i just went ahead w the next step and typed out

`git push origin master`

annnnd now its all uploaded...

im still a little shaky on what 'origin' is ... and what each piece of that line ACTUALLY do

Comment: This really is more of a question for superuser.com i think.

Comment: @halkeye: Er, SO is well-established as the place to ask version control questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you run

```
$ git remote
```

by itself you should get a list of remotes that are setup.

then you can do:

```
$ git remote rm origin
```

to remove the origin remote.

```
$ git remote --help
```

Will give you more information about the "git remote" command

Answer (score 1):

You can see what your origin currently is using this:

```
git remote show origin
```

And you can remove it like this:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Answer (score 1):

***origin*** does not describe something Git specific, it's just a name for a remote location. As mentioned you can see what remotes are currently in your repo by calling

```
git remote
```

to remove a **remote** use

```
git remote rm <your-remote-name>
```

in this case your remote name is ***origin***

Comment: Does git default to the first remote in `.git/config` (and "origin" just usually happens to be the first remote) when no remote is specified, or are there any other way the default is determined? Previously I've just assumed that "origin" were a magic name for the default remote, but magic names would be a quite strange...